# how can i check ObservableCollection's "CollectionChanged" event is null or not

Tags: c#

In ObservableCollection how can i check CollectionChanged event is null or not, 
This statement throws syntax error

```
 if (studentList.CollectionChanged == null)
```

ErrorMessage:

The event 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Sample Code:

```
 public class School
    {
        public School()
        {
            studentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();            
            //only when studentList.CollectionChanged is empty i want 
            // to execute the below statement
            studentList.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged;
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> studentList { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. Why is it that you want to, and though?

Comment: Good question, In the above code it will get executed only once. But in my actual scenario while serializing & de-serializing i loose the collectionchanged event, so i implement my own ondeserialized method and attache the collectionchanged programmatic. there i need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events aren't delegate instances.

Try this:

```
public class StudentList : ObservableCollection<Student>
{
    public int CountOfHandlers { get; private set; }

    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add {if (value != null) CountOfHandlers += value.GetInvocationList().Length;}
        remove { if (value != null)CountOfHandlers -= value.GetInvocationList().Length; }
    }
}

public class School
{
    public School()
    {
        studentList = new StudentList();
        //only when studentList.CollectionChanged is empty i want 
        // to execute the below statement
        if (studentList.CountOfHandlers == 0)
        {
            studentList.CollectionChanged += studentList_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public StudentList studentList { get; set; }

    private void studentList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){}
}

public class Student { }
```

Comment: Thanks, i handled it in same manner you said with slight difference                                                           private event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler _collectionChanged;
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_collectionChanged == null)
            {
                _collectionChanged += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            _collectionChanged -= value;
        }

    }

Answer (score 4):

You cannot see whether or not an event has handlers attached from outside of the class that owns the event.  You'll have to find a different solution to the problem you're trying to solve.